# How does the geometry for constructing a declining vertical sundial work?

Tags: the-sun, time

I understand how to construct South-facing vertical an horizontal sundials and the geometry behind their construction by projecting an equatorial sundial into a plane, but I can't quite get how to do that for a declined plane.

Comment: http://www.pandy.me.uk/sundials/wd_calc.htm may help

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_for_vertical_declining_dials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the following useful; scroll down to "Vertical Declining Sundial".

https://web.archive.org/web/20101214092541/http://www.walkingshadow.info/Publications/Scratch.pdf

Comment: Welcome. Please [provide context for links](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to give the reader some idea what's there.

Comment: The problem with link-only answers is that if the link breaks the answer becomes useless to future readers. It's hard to recreate that entire section here, (slides 16-22)  but if you can add at least a quick summary that will make this a better Stack Exchange answer. I looked at it and it's over my head, otherwise I'd just add it myself. *Thanks!*

Comment: The link broke :(